# Is Firebase Blaze storage and database pricing billed as full GB (downloaded + stored)?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

Everything here https://firebase.google.com/pricing/ that says "/GB" in Blaze plan, if I have less than GB will the price be calculated lower (like Amazon Web Service's) or billed as full GB?

Want to move from AWS but my app has rather small database/storage but requires large amount of access that it exceeded Spark plan. It would be a shame if Firebase bill me full $5 for realtime database that have barely anything. (In that case stick with AWS might be better)

I know this should go to their support but unfortunately this page https://firebase.google.com/support/ told me to come here, and their direct support is capped at 5 times per year..

Comment: From a technical standpoint, they probably aren't going to allocate partial-GB to you. It would make sense that they would round up your usage to the nearest GB, meaning they would charge you $5.

Comment: OP, if you want to really know, try asking https://cloud.google.com/contact/ - They are who you really need to ask and this way you don't ping your firebase support limit.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39629929/how-is-firebase-realtime-database-storage-calculated

Comment: The link explain how GB averages in a month, but not how that translate to cost per month. Let's say : I had 29 days where I had 1MB and 1 day where I had 2MB, the average is 29/30*1 + 1/30*2 = 0.967 + 0.067 = 1.033 MB. Then, will I get charge 1.033 MB or 1 GB? (or 5 GB?)

Answer (score 0):

Prorated. Calculated lower.

`Storage charges are prorated on a per-object basis`

https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing

(referenced as `"2) This is the estimated pricing for common usage. Firebase Storage free limits are enforced daily and refreshed at midnight Pacific Time. In the Blaze plan, fees for Firebase Storage are based on usage volume. Firebase Storage usage fees are processed as Google Cloud Storage usage fees. For more information, see Google Cloud Storage Pricing."` in the fine print)

Comment: Thank you. I am not an English native so I have guessed that prorated = calculated and missed that. What about Realtime Database? Is that count as a "storage" too?

Comment: I don't think "prorated" has anything to do with how many GB are determined. That term refers to having a reduced price for partial months. It's relevant for if you started/ended a billing plan mid-month.