# How is storage size calculated in Firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

There is a very good documentation for [firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/storage-size).
Also I found a good explanation for database size-tracking during a month, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39629929/how-is-firebase-realtime-database-storage-calculated).
But I still don't understand, how is the size of a RTDB calculated.
For instance, are indices part of the calculation?

How can I calculate or predict the storage size?

Comment: TBH I'm surprised this question doesn't have more upvotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*firebaser here*

The realtime database charges for storage of the JSON data only. So imagine that you read the root of the database, and then call `JSON.stringify(root)` on that snapshot. That's the storage you're charged for.

There is no additional charge for indexes that you define.

You're of course also charged for bandwidth usage.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Would be nice to find this in the docs. Especially if it is so easy to understand. 
Also good to know that indices do not cost anything.